# Update data from one table to another in vertical table

Tags: mysql

I understand basically the concepts of UPDATE to use data in one table to update another similar table. However the table data I have to update to is arranged in a 'vertical' manner as opposed to the 'horizontal' manner of the input table. This query works if I limit it to just one record :

```
SELECT @userid:=user_id,@club:=CLUB, @financialdate:=FINANCIALDATE
FROM wpty_sa_tmp_update where user_id = 1;
UPDATE wpty_cimy_uef_data SET VALUE = @financialdate WHERE user_id = @userid and field_id = 16;
UPDATE wpty_cimy_uef_data SET VALUE = @club WHERE user_id = @userid and field_id = 8;
```

If I remove the WHERE user_id clause, it does not update ..  what am I missing?
Obviously I can't create a join of any sort because the 2 tables don't share a common ID or key

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could actually do this from a single update statement:

```
UPDATE wpty_cimy_uef_data wc
INNER JOIN wpty_sa_tmp_update ws
    ON wc.user_id = ws.user_id AND ws.user_id = 1
SET
    VALUE = CASE field_id WHEN 16 THEN ws.FINANCIALDATE
                          WHEN 8  THEN ws.CLUB END
WHERE
    field_id IN (8, 16);
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, that seems to do the required updates..  will have a play with it